# How to increment/decrement column based on value of other column in Pyspark

Tags: python, pyspark

I have audit log data in Pyspark that I am trying to figure out how many people are logged on to the system at any given time.

So for example the dataframe I am working has the following structure

```
time    src_comp    auth_orient
1       C1          LogOn
2       C1          LogOn
2       C1          LogOn
3       C2          LogOn
3       C1          LogOff
4       C1          LogOn
4       C2          LogOff
5       C1          LogOn
6       C2          LogOn
6       C3          LogOff
```

Then from my code I want to create another column that shows how many people are logged on, like below. I also don't want the loggedon column to ever go negative, so if someone logs out of a system that I wasn't tracking I don't want to decrement the column:

Expected Output:

```
time    src_comp    LoggedOn
1       C1          1
2       C1          2
3       C2          1
3       C1          1
3       C1          2
4       C2          0
5       C1          3
6       C2          1
6       C3          0
```

I have the following code that I tried and got an error.

```
auth_dataset.groupby(auth_dataset.time,auth_dataset.src_comp).agg(F.when(auth_dataset.strt=='LogOn',number+=1).otherwise(number-=1))
```

Comment: What's your expected output?

Comment: It was the second dataframe, I edited the post for clarification.

Comment: Is that just `logOn = 1` and `logOff = 0`?

Comment: No, I realized my example is limited, if anything if logon ++1 if logoff --1, for a given timeframe and src comp.

Comment: Then you would need to provide a better example; And also not provide data as image if you can so that it would be easier for others to copy data and experiment.

Comment: Gotcha, I went through and updated the example. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try the following code. It sums up all values (1 and -1) and `greatest(0,col)` functions makes sure that it would never go negative.

```
auth_dataset.groupby('time','src_comp')\
.agg(F.sum(F.when(auth_dataset.auth_orient == 'LogOn', F.lit(1)).otherwise(F.lit(-1))).alias('LoggedOn'))\
.withColumn('LoggedOn', F.greatest(F.lit(0),'LoggedOn'))\
.sort('time','src_comp').show()
```

Answer (score -1):

it Question not Answer

time    src_comp    auth_orient
1       C1          LogOn
2       C2          LogOn
2       C3          LogOn
3       C1          LogOn
3       C2          LogOff
4       C1          LogOn
4       C1          LogOff
5       C2          LogOn
6       C3          LogOn
6       C1          LogOff

in src_comp column values are reset to initial value then how to give a group number for that.
Ex: C1, C2, C3 as group1. C1, C2 as group2. C1 as group3. C1, C2, C3 as group4. C1 as group5. when value resets to C1 from there i want to give a group number in another column in pyspark. how can i do that.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/31281516)